# Взять котировки с yahoo

Tags: java

Для того, чтобы скачать котировки с yahoo finance достаточно на пайтоне сделать так. А как сделать тоже самое на джава?

```css
from pandas_datareader import data

a = 'AAPL'
aapl = data.DataReader(a, 'yahoo', '1990-01-01')
aapl.to_csv('C:/aapl_data.csv')
```

Comment: Воспользоваться ихним апи

Comment: Как я понимаю pandas_datareader - это некая библиотека для работы с данными с яху, гугла и т.д. Для того чтобы код был так же прост на Java, надо найти такую же библиотеку, либо написать самому.

Comment: Да, я подумываю над тем чтобы написать библиотеку, я уже выучил как складывать две переменные и писать ответ в println.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полноценное решение на java с хорошими примерами. Кода будет почти так же мало как на python'e

http://financequotes-api.com/

Если покапаетесь в исходниках то сможете понять как работать с Yahoo api ну или же почитайте следующую инструкцию

http://meumobi.github.io/stocks%20apis/2016/03/13/get-realtime-stock-quotes-yahoo-finance-api.html

Answer (score 1):

Низкоуровневый вариант как-то так будет выглядеть:

```
package javatest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void urlToFile(URL url, File file) throws Exception {
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
        from.clear();
        Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();
        to.clear();

        from.set(2016, 2, 15);
        to.set(2016, 2, 28);

        urlToFile(
                new URL(String.format(
                        "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=%s&b=%s&c=%s&d=%s&e=%s&f=%s&g=d&ignore=.csv",
                        from.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        from.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        from.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        to.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        to.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                        to.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                )),
                new File("file.csv")
        );
    }
}
```